# How to do this in HTML?

Tags: html

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;">Nr abc</label><span id="valBillingAccountNumber" style="display: inline-block; color: Red; padding-left:1em" >*</span><label style="display: inline-block; width:140px;">Test</label>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;">Nr abcdefg</label><span id="valBillingAccountNumber" style="display: inline-block; color: Red; padding-left:1em" >*</span><label style="display: inline-block; width:140px;">Test</label>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;">Nr abcd</label><span id="valBillingAccountNumber" style="display: inline-block; color: Red; padding-left:1em" >*</span><label style="display: inline-block; width:140px;">Test</label>
  </div>
```

I want the resulting page to look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Almost done, but not perfect. I need to move star at first label in each row. [How get this effect?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8tYu.png)
Star need to be in another label because i will hide this sometimes.

```html
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; width:140px;">Nr abc</label><span id="valBillingAccountNumber" style="display: inline-block; width:140px; color: Red; padding-left:1em" >*</span><label style="display: inline-block; width:140px;">Test</label>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; width:140px;">Nr abcdefg</label><span id="valBillingAccountNumber" style="display: inline-block; width:140px; color: Red; padding-left:1em" >*</span><label style="display: inline-block; width:140px;">Test</label>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; width:140px;">Nr abcd</label><span id="valBillingAccountNumber" style="display: inline-block; width:140px; color: Red; padding-left:1em" >*</span><label style="display: inline-block; width:140px;">Test</label>
  </div>
```